# Office 2010 Styled Help

Tags: wpf, windows-7, chm, office-2010

Hi In Office 2010 you get a popup window if you click on ? or press F1
(Sorry for the Danish text)

[image: Word Help F1]

[image: Word Help]

Before I start coding my own popup Window in WPF, I would like to know if there is some standard behind it, like the good old .CHM file. [Microsoft Compiled HTML Help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called Vista (Assistance Platform) Help.

Since I have to support XP, I haven't looked into it really (stuck to CHM), but Vista+ has some other helpsystem. I've dug the following links up from my Help link collection

- http://helpware.net/aphelp/default.htm
- http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_AP_Help/ap_help.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Help_1.0

Microsofts Doxygen like tool "Sandcastle" also seems to use it:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandcastle_%28software%29